# Is there any qt signal for sql database change?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qsqldatabase, change-notification

I wrote a C++ program using Qt. some variables inside my algorithm are changed outside of my program and in a web page. every time the user changes the variable values in the web page I modify a pre-created SQL database.
Now I want my code to change the variables value during run time without to stop the code. there is two options :

1. Every n seconds check the database and retrieve the variables `value` -> this is not good since I have to check if database content is changed every n seconds (it might be without any change for years. Also I don't want to check if the database content is changed)
2. Every time the database is changed my Qt program emits a signal so by catching this signal I can refresh the variables value, This seems an optimal solution and I want to write a code for this part

The C++ part of my code is:

```cpp
void Update Database()
{
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("Mydataset");

    db.setUserName("user");
    db.setPassword("pass");

    if(!db.open())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Error is: "<<db.lastError();
        qFatal("Failed To Connect");
    }
    QSqlQuery qry;
    qry.exec("SELECT * from tblsystemoptions");
    QSqlRecord rec = qry.record();
    int cols = rec.count();
    qry.next();
    MCH = qry.value(0).toString();  //some global variables used in other functions
    MCh = qry.value(1).toString();
    // ... this goes on ...


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing. The Qt event loop and the database are not connected in any way. You only fetch/alter/delete/insert/... data and that's it. Option 1 is the one you have to do. There are ways to use TRIGGER on the server side to launch external scripts but this would not help you very much.

Comment: the external script could connect with the Qt app and that can then trigger a signal but that is quite a bit of work

Comment: Yeah. But the question here is: How should it connect? Per socket? If the server is not under heavy load and the data you try to fetch is a cheap select, i would do a timed fetch. Everything else is rather complicated. I think OP needs a push-notification service ;-)

Comment: Dear DOminik is it possible by using sockets ? I think it's easy both in php and qt to communicate through a socket isn't it ?

Comment: I am by far no expert on php but using sockets will only shift the problem because you have to constantly connect to a server that will notify you (e.g. by writing to the socket) that something changed. I do not know the type of app and the restrictions you are facing. But fetching e.g. a timestamp in a table and compare it to the local timing of your machine is by far a much more easy job than using a socket to communicate to a app that must be triggered by the databases. But i do not know the requirements of your task. Are you having bandwidth limits, complex selects to get the elements,...?

Comment: No it's just a simple table with just bunch of data ... both of this application run in a single pc and they can interact with each other thorough system RAM .... I've heard that sockets are a good candidate for my problem but I don't know anything about its efficiency ...

Comment: What's the second application? I think i don't get it? You have two applications that do inter-process communication and a sql-server on the same machine?

Answer (score 13):

`QSqlDriver` supports notifications which emit a signal when a specific event has occurred. To subscribe to an event just use `QSqlDriver::subscribeToNotification( const QString & name )`. When an event that you’re subscribing to is posted by the database the driver will emit the notification() signal and your application can take appropriate action.

```
db.driver()->subscribeToNotification("someEventId");
```

The message can be posted automatically from a trigger or a stored procedure. The message is very lightweight: nothing more than a string containing the name of the event that occurred.

You can connect the `notification(const QString&)`signal to your slot like:

```
QObject::connect(db.driver(), SIGNAL(notification(const QString&)), this, SLOT(refreshView()));
```

I should note that this feature is not supported by MySQL as it does not have an event posting mechanism.

Comment: To be honest, i was not aware of this. This is actually pretty cool ... thanks a lot. +1

Comment: Mhh ... are you sure that QMYSQL supports notifications because i do not find any evidence that MySQL supports this. I am just curious because i was surprised i was aware of this (if it is available) awesome feature.

Comment: Ok ... i have checked it and it does not work since MySQL (at least in version 5.5.32) does not support such a mechanism. I assume you did not test it?

Comment: Yeah it is not available for QMYSQL. I was not targeting MySQL.

Comment: Ok. Maybe you should edit your answer since it is kind of unrelated to the question of OP who it clearly targeting MySQL.

Comment: Seems only PostgreSQL driver supports event notifications. The rest would require polling.